# What are the exact words in this video?

Tags: listening

I'm trying to make an exact transcript of this video:
https://youtu.be/sKOlfR5OcB4

There are several parts that I can't determine.

22:43 **This (??? construction) is called the two fluid model for liquid helium II.**

It sounds to me like "far", but doesn't make any sense.

33:40 **Moving (??) the detector away from the heater increases the delay.**

Although it doesn't need any word between "moving" and "the" to make sense, it still sounds like there's a very short word there. Or not? I can't be sure.

35:35 **The model is (????), but many of its elements survive.**

Sounds like "false" to me. But I don't feel it goes very well with "survive". In my understanding, "some elements survive" would suggest that the rest parts of the model are not just incorrect or untrue, but are already gone, no longer there anymore. So I figure it should be some word synonymous with "discarded" or "dead" or "destroyed" or something. I just don't know whether my understanding is right.

Comment: I couldn't hear the first. There is no word between **Moving** and **the detector**. The last sounds like **false** but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

21:23 ... 22:43   This state of affairs forces us to think of helium II, ... 
... This **thought** construction is called the two fluid model for liquid helium II.

33:40   Moving **[audio-processing distortion that began during "Moving"]** the detector away from the heater increases the delay.

35:35   The model is **false [distorted by another audio glitch]**, but many of its elements survive.

<sub>(Interesting to actually see these historic demonstrations.)</sub>